# Error processing a csv file in Keras

Tags: python, csv, numpy, keras

I'm working on building an LSTM recurrent neural network that processes a set of texts and uses them to predict the author of new texts. I have a CSV file containing a single column of long text entries that is comma separated like this:

"sample text here","more text here","extra text written here"

This goes on for a few thousand entries. I'm trying to load this so I can feed it through the Keras Tokenizer and then use it in training my model but I'm  stuck on an error originating on the first call to the Tokenizer where it kicks back with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
  t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
File "I:\....text.py",
line 175, in fit_on_texts
   self.split)
File "I:\....text.py",
line 47, in text_to_word_sequence
text = text.translate(translate_map)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I'm very new to python, but as far as I can tell the issue is that the Tokenizer is expecting strings, but it's getting passed an ndarray instead. What I can't seem to manage is finding a way to pass it the correct thing, and I would really appreciate any advice. I've been working on this for a couple days now and it's just not coming to me.

Here's the relevant section of my code:

```
    X_train = pandas.read_csv('I:\\xTrain.csv', sep=",", header=None, error_bad_lines=False).as_matrix()
    t  = Tokenizer(lower=False)
    t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
    t.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='count', lower=False)
```

I've tried reading it in a variety of ways, including using numpy.loadtxt. The error has varied a bit with the methods, but it's always that I'm trying to feed the wrong kind of input to the Tokenizer and I can't seem to work out how to get the right kind. What am I missing here? Thanks for taking the time to read!

**Update**

With help from furas, I discovered that my array was two columns wide and have successfully removed the second empty column. Unfortunately, this seems to have simply changed the error I'm getting slightly. It now reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
  t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
File "I:\....text.py",
line 175, in fit_on_texts
   self.split)
File "I:\....text.py",
line 47, in text_to_word_sequence
text = text.translate(translate_map)
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

The only change is that numpy.ndarray is now numpy.int64. It looks to me like this is an int array now, even though it contains strings of text, so I'm attempting to find a way to convert it into a string array.

```
del X_train[1]
X_train[0] = Y_train[0].apply(str)
```

Is the code I've tried so far. The first line strips the extra column, but the second line seems to do nothing. I'm still trying to figure out how to get this data into the proper format.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you read documentation ? mayby it doesn't work with pandas dataframe or numpy array.

Comment: There, I updated with the rest of the traceback though it doesn't really offer much. I've read through the documentation for this and what feels like nearly everything else, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get it the right input. I'm beyond frustrated at this point, I've never struggled this much before with something that I suspect is very simple.

Comment: `fit_on_texts` need list with strings (1-dimensional list/array) but it seems you have list with arrays (2-dimensional list/array). Use print() to see what you have in X_train.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. It's printing my values for the first column, but then a second column of "nan" values. I assume that's the equivalent of null, so there's a second column of null values for some reason. The related text strings are extremely long so it's a really cluttered view, otherwise I'd post an example here. I'm looking in to why I've got a second column right now, thanks! Hopefully that's the source of my problem.